# Sources for embedding secondary math into technical classes?

Tags: reference-request, technology-in-education

I've taken a job for the next school year, which will involve embedding secondary math (algebra, geometry and trigonometry) into technical programs such as drafting and electrician school.

Does anyone know of any resources that would be available for me to use to learn more about this? So far my educational career has only been in a more traditional classroom.

Answer (score 4):

There is a California (US) organization called [Career Technical Education](http://cteteach.cteonline.org/) that offers several courses, from Agriculture
to Transportation.
Below is a snapshot from the [Engineering and Architecture course](http://cteteach.cteonline.org/portal/default/Curriculum/Viewer/Curriculum?action=2&cmobjid=804363&view=viewer&refcmobjid=777121),
which
appears to integrate mathematics into drafting, perspective drawing, etc.

---

[image: CTE]

---

It appears that all the resources can be accessed for free.

Comment: Thank you! This looks like exactly what I was needing.